# percentage distribution of profits

Tags: algorithm, math

currently i'm working on an little virtual project. On an registration phase, users can buy a ticket for one coin.

If the registration process ended, the coins will be stored in an pot-system. 20% of them goes to the jackpot and the other ones (80%) will be paid out randomly to the registered users.

**Yet, here comes the problem:**

The 80% of coins will be split to a variable winning places. Default, we get drawn 10 winners, but these can be changed on administrators side. An admin can say *"okay, next round we want to raffling 50 winners"* or something like that.

What's the best solution/algorithm to calculate the profit for the variable winners? The calculation must be carried out so that the first place have an higher profit than the Last - A kind of profits staggering.

**Examples**

Each round, as admin you can set the number of winners.

The first round the admin set 10 winning places. 100 Coins will be
distribute to 10 random users.

The second round the admin set 25 winning places. 70 Coins will be
distribute to 25 random users.

On another round the admin set 33 winning places. 500 Coins will be
distribute to 33 random users.

Comment: I want to update the question with little examples

Comment: Are the coins divisible? That is, can a user get half a coin?

Comment: I am not sure you need an algorithm for that. The expected gain can be determined analytically according to the probability distribution of your lottery.

Answer (score 1):

You would need bounds for the random amount given to each winner (in sequence), so that the profit does not increase as you *go down* the list.

- Set the higher bound (non-inclusive) to the amount of money won by the previous winner, except for first place - set this to the total amount of money
- Set the lower bound (inclusive) to the amount of money left *divided by* the number of winners left on the list
- For the last place winner give him the rest (or keep some for 'charity' :))

Comment: same thinks. I think i want to try to use linear math operations for that.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss what do you mean?